# Rails 4.2 send email after post published

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple Rails 4.2 blogging app. 
I have created a boolean called 'published'. Only the published articles are shown on the blog.

I would like to send subscribers an email when a new post is marked 'published'.

I have the subscriptions set up through a Mailchimp list and I send the emails with Mandrill. 
How can I get an email to send after I check 'published' on a post? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the user submitting the form or just checking the check box?  Either way, you should be able to generate the email in the corresponding controller action, although if it just triggered on the check box, you will need to do with AJAX.  Probably better to do it on form submit to ensure box is "permanently" checked.  What part do you need help with?

Comment: The published works on form submit, so no AJAX needed. But what would the controller action look like?

Comment: It would be better if you could show us what you have and explain either what is not working or where you are stuck (specifically).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, something like this might work

```
def publish
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.publish
  begin
    @mailer = PublishedNotificationMailer.published_email(@post).deliver
    render :json => '', :status => 200
  rescue
    render :json => '', :status => 422
  end
end
```